# Why does an ASP.NET project only build in docker if using an intermediate container?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, nano

So I have two docker files.  One builds, one fails with an "SDK" error.  This is the one that FAILS:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS base
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TestApi"
RUN dotnet publish "TestApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestApi.dll"]
```

This is the one that SUCCEEDS:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS base
FROM base
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TestApi"
RUN dotnet publish "TestApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestApi.dll"]
```

Literally the only difference is the "FROM base" call.  However, when running the first one, I get an error message.  The second one successfully builds and runs the API.  What gives?

The one that fails throws this error, though I've found the errors are often misleading with Visual Studio / Docker:

```
It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
```